# Were these hypercomplex number sets already defined in the literature for some $n\neq 3$? Are they associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, hypercomplex-numbers

I've been studying about hypercomplex numbers for the past few days, and then a question arised:

It looks quite natural to me to define the following set (based on the definition of quaternions):

$X = \{a_0+a_1i_1+...+a_ni_n : a_j\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $j\}$

And define a product on $X$ simply extending the following rules, for all $j$:

$$i_j^2 = -1$$
$$i_{j}i_{j+1}=i_{j+2}$$
$$i_{j+1}i_{j}=-i_{j+2}$$
(here we are considering the indices modulo $n$, so that $i_{n}i_{1} = i_2$, for example).

And define addition in the natural/obvious way.

Then, by extending this we also would have defined any product of type $i_ji_k$, and by applyig the distributive law, we would have a product on all $X$ - unless I missed something wrong here, off course!

My question: is this set with the multiplication given above already defined in the literature (for some $n\neq 3$ - since the case $n=3$ is exactly the quaternions case - I suppose that maybe $n$ should be odd or $\equiv 3 \;(mod \; 4)$, but I'm not sure)? Where could I find it? Also, would this algebra be associative? (I know it would not be a division ring for $n>3$, and it is obviously not commutative)

Any book or article recomendation would be appreciated (since the ones I've read do not answer these questions), and also any comments about the above.

(rmk.: it doesn't matter if this algebra is "nice" or not, but I would like to know if it is well defined and associative, since it looks very "natural" and similar to the quaternions)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the  Hurwitz theorem ?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)

Comment: @EmilioNovati I have already seen this page in Wikipedia. I know that if the algebra I defined above is well defined it should not be "nice" and the "absolute value" would not work well - but I wanted particularly to know if it is associative (and if it is well defined), since in this case I could try to look at its group of units (groups are associative), wich is an area I'm interested in. It looks hard to verify it, I tryed and couldn't. Since it is a very natural definition, I supposed that it should be elsewhere in the literature for me to look up (seems like it is not - but maybe it is).

Comment: No, it's not associative: $$i_1i_3=i_1(i_1i_2)=(i_1i_1)i_2=-i_2$$ but also $$i_1i_3=(-i_4i_3)i_3=-i_4(i_3i_3)=i_4$$ Contradiction.

Comment: great! Thanks @mr_e_man

Comment: That is for $n=4$. For $n=5$ we still would have $i_1i_3=-i_2$ as above; the other way would give $$i_1i_3=(-i_5i_4)i_3=i_5(-i_4i_3)=i_5i_5=-1$$

Comment: For $n=6$: $$i_1i_3=(-i_6i_5)i_3=-i_6(-i_4i_3)i_3=i_6i_4(i_3i_3)=-i_6i_4=(i_5i_4)i_4=i_5(i_4i_4)=-i_5$$

Comment: For $n=7$: $$i_1i_3=(-i_7i_6)i_3=-i_7(-i_5i_4)i_3=i_7i_5(i_4i_3)=i_7i_5(-i_5)=i_7(-i_5i_5)=i_7$$ Odd, 3 mod 4, doesn't matter.

Comment: @mr_e_man This case n=7 completes the answer that it is not associative. Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: As the answer says, you haven't defined the product for non-adjacent indices. Those can be defined arbitrarily, given that it's not associative. Any multiplication table for $n$ basis vectors, which is an $n\times n\times n$ "matrix", uniquely defines an algebra. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Structure_coefficients

Comment: @mr_e_man thank you, I will see the link you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as $n=4$ you will need additional rules to fill in the product table so you can determine things such as $i_1i_3=?, i_2i_4=?$, etc.

Recursive definition of basis elements can be a productive idea, however.

For example, the basis elements of the Cayley-Dickson algebras can be defined that way as follows:

1. $i_p^2=-1$
2. If $i_pi_q=i_r$ then $i_qi_r=-i_p$
3. $i_1i_{2k}=i_{2k+1}$
4. $i_{2k}i_{2k+1}=i_1$
5. $i_{2k+1}i_1=i_{2k}$

These last three compose a *quaternion triple* and can be abbreviated: $(1, 2k, 2k+1)$

When $k=1$ this will give the product table for the quaternions.

To get higher dimensions (which will be powers of two} you need additional *doubling rules*. There are several options for these. Here is one such.

If $(p,q,r)$ then

1. $(2p,2q,2r)$
2. $(2p,2r+1,2q+1)$
3. $(2q,2p+1,2r+1)$
4. $(2r,2q+1,2p+1)$

If you start with the quaternion triples from the basis elements of the quaternions and add the triples for $k=2,k=3$, namely $(1,4,5),(1,6,7)$ and apply the doubling rules you will get the basis elements of the Octonions. Repeat the process and you get the sedenions, etc.

So you should experiment with your rule and see if you can find additional rules which allow you to fill in your product table in a meaningful way.

Comment: For n=4, we would have, for example: $i_1i_3 = i_1(i_1i_2)$, I thought that it was associative (as someone pointed out above it is not) and that we would have $i_1(i_1i_2)=i_1^2i_2=-i_2$. Thank you very much for your answer! Now it is clear what I was missing.